# I want to read an array of integers from a file and publish them on a topic

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
 ros::Publisher publisher = nh.advertise<std_msgs::Int32MultiArray>("Topic_1",1);

  std_msgs::Int32MultiArray vec;

  int i=0;

  ifstream infile("array1.txt");
  while(infile >> temp)
    {
      vec[i++] = temp;
      // publisher.publish(temp);
    }
  publisher.publish(vec);
```

1. > #but I'm getting this error after I run the command  $catkin_make in
   > my
   > workspace

```
 ...
    [ 85%] [ 92%] [100%] Built target subscriber
    Building CXX object task/CMakeFiles/publisher_1.dir/src/publisher_1.cpp.o
    Building CXX object task/CMakeFiles/publisher_2.dir/src/publisher_2.cpp.o
    /home/kv/krssg/src/task/src/publisher_1.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
    /home/kv/krssg/src/task/src/publisher_1.cpp:27:10: error: no match for ‘operator[]’ (operand types are ‘std_msgs::Int32MultiArray’ and ‘int’)
           vec[i++] = temp;
              ^
    /home/kv/krssg/src/task/src/publisher_2.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
    /home/kv/krssg/src/task/src/publisher_2.cpp:25:11: error: no match for ‘operator[]’ (operand types are ‘std_msgs::Int32MultiArray’ and ‘int’)
           vec2[i++] = temp;
               ^
    make[2]: *** [task/CMakeFiles/publisher_1.dir/src/publisher_1.cpp.o] Error 1
    make[1]: *** [task/CMakeFiles/publisher_1.dir/all] Error 2
    make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
    make[2]: *** [task/CMakeFiles/publisher_2.dir/src/publisher_2.cpp.o] Error 1
    make[1]: *** [task/CMakeFiles/publisher_2.dir/all] Error 2
    make: *** [all] Error 2
    Invoking "make -j4 -l4" failed
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227856/i-want-to-read-an-array-of-integers-from-a-file-and-publish-them-on-a-topic/) by [anonymous25787](https://answers.ros.org/users/25787/anonymous25787/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2016-03-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are trying to acces the MultiArray directly over the `[]` operator.
Check the [message definition here](http://docs.ros.org/api/std_msgs/html/msg/Int32MultiArray.html).

You need to do a

```
vec.data[i++] = temp;
```

as, the `data` field is actually the vector representation.
Also, make sure that the vector is big enough, so you don't get an index error. Use either the respective `resize` function or do `push_back` the new values.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-03-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1